# Ansible 'synchronize' overwrites folder even though delete=no

Tags: linux, ansible, rsync, overwrite

In my Ansible role "xen", I have this task:

```
---
- name: Install Xen
  synchronize: src=install/
               dest=/
               archive=yes
               delete=no
```

I want to copy the following structure to the destination without overwriting files in the existing folders like `/boot` and `/lib64`:

```
root@node51 [~]# tree -L 1 /etc/ansible/xenhost/xen/files/install
/etc/ansible/xenhost/xen/files/install
├── boot
├── etc
├── lib64
├── usr
└── var

5 directories, 0 files
```

The task worked, but **it replaced all the files in `/lib64`**.  That killed my server:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls /lib64/
-bash: /usr/bin/ls: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Here's the verbose task output, truncated for brevity:

```
TASK: [xen | Install Xen] ***************************************************** 
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1448470134.66-193795609318676 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1448470134.66-193795609318676']
<127.0.0.1> PUT /tmp/tmpb7EusD TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1448470134.66-193795609318676/synchronize
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', u'LANG=C LC_CTYPE=C /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1448470134.66-193795609318676/synchronize; rm -rf /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1448470134.66-193795609318676/ >/dev/null 2>&1']
changed: [192.168.0.123] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "rsync --delay-updates -FF --compress --archive --rsh 'ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' \"/etc/ansible/xenhost/xen/files/install/\" \"root@192.168.0.123:/\"", "msg": "…truncated…"}
```

Curiously, the task didn't erase the existing files in `/boot`.

I made sure to specify `delete=no` explicitly, just in case, so it should *not* "[Delete files that don't exist (after transfer, not before) in the `src` path.](http://web.archive.org/web/20150905075202/http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html)"

**Why did the Ansible 'synchronize' module replace `/lib64` but copy to `/boot` as expected?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that **`/lib64` is not a directory**.  It is a symbolic link:

```
[root@localhost ~]# file /lib64
/lib64: symbolic link to `usr/lib64'
```

By having Ansible 'synchronize' `rsync` your `lib64` directory, it **removes the symbolic link and puts an actual folder in its place**.

As a result, the libraries in `/usr/lib64` are no longer reachable from `/lib64`, which is why everything that depended on finding libraries in `/lib64` failed:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ldd /usr/bin/ls
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa9118000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fe4b9630000)
    libcap.so.2 => /lib64/libcap.so.2 (0x00007fe4b9428000)
    libacl.so.1 => /lib64/libacl.so.1 (0x00007fe4b9218000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe4b8e50000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007fe4b8be8000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fe4b89c0000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe4b87b8000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe4b9860000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib64/libattr.so.1 (0x00007fe4b85b0000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe4b8390000)
```

---

### Remedy

Copy to `/usr/lib64` instead.  Put the libraries to copy in `/etc/ansible/xenhost/xen/files/install/usr/lib64` instead of in `/etc/ansible/xenhost/xen/files/install/lib64`, and make sure the latter path does not exist.